# Inserting hat and subscript

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.121 \^{p_{ijk}}
                  = \^{\pi}_{ijk} = \fract{y_{ijk}}{n}
```

Comment: What can you be trying to type??!!! What is this `\fract`command?

Comment: @Bernard, I am trying to obtain p hat underscore ijk as output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, if we intend to place a hat on p, then should a package be installed. I have already installed the amsmath package.

Comment: @Sana: I don't understand what you're trying to say. You don't need a package for your requirements

Comment: In math mode, you need to use `\hat` and not  `\^`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `\hat` for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \hat{p}_{ijk} = \hat{\pi}_{ijk} = \frac{y_{ijk}}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of these?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \[ \widehat{\pi_{ijk}},\quad \widehat{\pi}_{ijk} = \frac{y_{ijk}}{n} \]%%

\end{document}
```

[image]